# Showing List in a Select tag in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{   
   System.out.println("items are"+list.get(i));
   out.println("<html><select><option>"+list.get(i)+"</option></select></html>");
}
```

i have few elements in my ArrayList list, and i want to show these elements in a select tag in my jsp.
I have done it but the select tag is repeating itself as it is in the loop.I am not able to print the elements in a single select tag.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you loop `html` tag everytime

Comment: @Mr. Alien cuz i dnt know how to iterate through the list with a single select tag..
If u know a better way. Please post some code that will be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ya go:

```
out.println("<html><select>") ;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{   
     out.println("<option>"+list.get(i)+"</option>");
}
out.println("</select></html>") ;
```

Generates:

```
<html>
<select>
 //loop begins here
 <option> option1 </option>
 <option> option2 </option>
     ....
 <option> option n </option>
 //loop ends here
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks its working..
I ll accept it in 7 minutes
Awesome @Lews Therin

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are iterating you are adding `html`  and `select` tags each time. HTML and select tag needs to be created only once.
Try this

```
out.println("<html><select>");
System.out.println("items are");
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{   
      System.out.println(list.get(i));
      out.println("<option>"+list.get(i)+"</option>");
}

out.println("</select></html>");
```

Comment: Working @Shiju
Accepted ur too

Thanks

Comment: i already accepted Lews's answer so i upvoted both the answers :)